# Can you debug Bun tests?

Tags: bun

I tried running `bun test --inspect`. It prints the Bun Inspector header:

```
bun test v1.0.0 (822a00c4)

lexer.test.ts:
--------------------- Bun Inspector ---------------------
Listening:
  ws://localhost:6499/2rmn49ur73
Inspect in browser:
  https://debug.bun.sh/#localhost:6499/2rmn49ur73
--------------------- Bun Inspector ---------------------
```

Unfortunately, it runs my tests, skipping over the `debugger` statements. Is there a way to make it pause?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--inspect-wait` flag when running tests to debug.

```
bun test --inspect-wait
```

According to [bun documentation](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/debugger#inspect-wait), your execution code will not execute until a debugger has attached to the running process.

Alternatively, use you can also use `--inspect-brk`. This automatically adds a debugger to the first line of code. Make sure to enable the `debugger statements` flag under `Breakpoints` on the left panel of the inspector to pause at `debugger` statements.

[image: Place to look for debugger flag in inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hack I came up with (a better answer would be appreciated). Busy wait for 10 seconds (enough time to open the inspector link):

```
const startTime = new Date();
while (new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime() < 10000) {}
debugger;
```